# Can i convert Figma Design to Jetpack Compose for my approach?

Tags: kotlin, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose, figma, figma-plugin

I am not sure if it is possible to have my app design completely converted to Android Studio using the Figma Relay plugin. In Figma I have designed an app with 5 different screens, NavigationDrawer, Toasts, AlertDialogs etc..
As a test, I converted one screen and found out that Android Studio makes a massive block of code out of it. Does anyone here has experience as a single developer that he can share with me?
Despite intensive research, some things have remained unclear to me. For example, if I create a textfield in Figma and then convert it, Jetpack doesn't recognize that this should be a textfield after the conversion. But since you are not supposed to directly edit the kotlin.file that Android Studio creates from the UI kit, I wonder how to do such things now?

I would also appreciate if someone can share a tutorial with me. The official Google Developer pages are not very helpful for such specific questions.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: The better approach is to make on your self